# How to stop redirecting mobile requests nginx flask?

Tags: python, nginx

Recently we secured our app with SSL. Websites and Postman automatically redirects to https and works correctly. But mobile devices doesn't work the same.  In mobile devices 301 response doesn't redirect to the new url. How can I stop mobile requests to redirect and let them work the same way as they were ? #Stuck#SOS

```
server {
    listen 443 default ssl;

    # ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/path/myfile.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/path/myfile.pem;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/path/myfile.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

    if ($http_user_agent ~* '(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino') {
        set $mobile_rewrite perform;
    }

    # Do not redirect mobile device requests
    if ($mobile_rewrite = perform){
        return http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Tell us more about your set up. Are you using nginx? Did you block port 80?

Comment: @AArias Added config file. And no we didn't block 80 port but we are redirecting incoming requests to 443.

Comment: as for me you create loop - you redirect mobile to the same url and it try again connect to the same url and again you check if it is mobile, etc. You should rather redirect other `if ($mobile_rewrite != perform){ return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri } ` and below put `location / {...}`

Comment: @TusharSheth I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want mobile devices to avoid https or to be redirected to https if they try http?

Comment: @AArias I want mobile devices to avoid https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just avoid this too many user agent and try with simple like

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ 'Android | iPhone') {
        set $mobile_rewrite perform;
    }
```